# Date Time issue with timezone

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, c#-3.0

In xamarin forms, but my time for HST is giving 1 hr difference than actual time on dateTime1

Im using

```
string timeZone="HST";
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
  TimeZoneInfo timezoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(x => x.StandardName.ToUpper() == timeZone.Trim().ToUpper());

DateTime dateTime1 = ConvertStringToDate(dateTimeNow, timezoneInfo);
                   
 private DateTime ConvertStringToDate(DateTime fomrttedDate, TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            DateTime finalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fomrttedDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime convertedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(finalDate, DateTimeKind.Utc), timeZoneInfo);
            return convertedDate;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using UtcNow?  Try without Utc : DataTime.Now.

Comment: "HST" isn't really a time zone, just like "PST" and "PDT" aren't time zones. Which time zone are you actually interested in? If you could provide a [mcve] which shows what you're expecting and what you're receiving, that would help too.

Comment: @jdweng: That sounds like a bad idea to me. Converting into one time zone can be tricky to start with - implicitly using the time zone of the system the code is running on introduces more complexity that we have no indication is required.

Comment: (I would generally suggest using the IANA time zone IDs if at all possible - if the platform you're running on doesn't support them, you might consider using my [Noda Time package](https://nodatime.org) to provide not only IANA time zone information, but also a better date/time API than the one that comes with .NET...)

Comment: "Im getting string timeZone="HST"" - from where? We don't have any context here. You may need to change your upstream code to get a *genuine* time zone ID.

Comment: Im getting string timeZone="HST" or  timeZoneDisplayName =(UTC-10:00) Hawaii from API which I need to use for timezone with dateTime.Now .                               
 What is best approach I can use for it?

Comment: Im getting string timeZone="HST" or timeZoneDisplayName =(UTC-10:00) Hawaii from API which I need to use for timezone with dateTime.Now . What is best approach I can use for it?  @JonSkeet

Comment: From what API? Is this something you can work on changing to provide a more "real" ID? (Again, we have no context.) It looks like the IANA time zone you want is America/Adak. But even with that information, we don't know why you're calling `Convert.ToDateTime` on something that's already a `DateTime`, or why you're calling `DateTime.SpecifyKind` with a kind of UTC on a value that's already in UTC... nor do we know the value you're expecting, or what's being returned. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/